# setting Pool as struct type leads to error

Tags: rust

I have a Problem setting Pool as a struct type.

```
use super::db::{init_connection, models};
actix_web::Responder;
use diesel::r2d2::Pool;

#[derive(Debug)]        
pub struct Basic {
    pool: Pool
}

impl Basic {
    pub fn new(&self) {
        self.pool = init_connection().unwind(); 
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error

```
pool: Pool
      ^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

As far as I understand "Pool" is the type. What else is required here?

Comment: `Pool` needs a type parameter: https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/r2d2/struct.Pool.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pool is a generic struct of type Pool, where M represents the trait to be implemented for database-specific logic to create a database connection.
For example, there are separate implementations of this trait for using with MySQL, Postgres, sqlite, mongodb etc. Depending on the database you want to use, look for the appropriate crate such as r2d2-mongodb, r2d2_sqlite etc.

For Mysql, one option is to use r2d2_mysql crate. This has a struct MysqlConnectionManager which implements the r2d2::ManageConnection trait. It can be used as shown:

```
// Imports
use r2d2::Pool;
use r2d2_mysql::MysqlConnectionManager;

// Define data type for connection pool. This can be part of app state
pool: Arc<Pool<MysqlConnectionManager>>,

// Initialize connection pool
let manager = r2d2_mysql::MysqlConnectionManager::new(builder);
let pool = Arc::new(r2d2::Pool::new(manager).unwrap());
```

Refer to crate docs here for example: https://github.com/outersky/r2d2-mysql

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I know that Pool is generic. In my case I actually use the Mysql implementation.

But M is, and that is propably my problem, the name of the Trait or is it not? And the trait is diesel::r2d2::Pool, right?

So what I need to do is:

    pub struct Basic {
        pool: <diesel::r2d2::Pool>
    }

Would that be right?

I am asking because I've tried this too and I the get

     self.pool = init_connection();
           ^^^^ unknown field

I think my problem is more fundamental and rooted in the misconception of what's happening here.